# Hidden text input

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I encountered a strange blocker at my project. I have to read from user 4 digits and pass it to another control (which presents it but in encrypted form). But there is a catch. My goal is to have only a keyboard, go next button if 4 digit are present and that previously mentioned control.

But how can I hide my textbox? My field where the digits will be kept has to be secret. (but I will need it in the next pages) So I need some kind of hidden textbox or some way to lock screen with keyboard and bind the keystrokes to some kind of property which allow me future bindings?

Hope I draw picture clearly enough.

Comment: How about using a `PasswordBox`?

Comment: It dosent solve my requirements. It has to be hidden field. User cannot know about existence of it. Something like a hidden field in a ASP form.

Comment: What about setting the opacity of the textbox to 0 and focus it programmatically with : MyTextBox.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard) ?

Answer (score 2):

You should put a TextBox (`tbDigitInput` in this example) behind the visible elements and focus on it like this:

```
this.tbDigitInput.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
```

You can really hide it using any element - maybe behind the canvas where you show your digits in encrypted form.

Note that hiding it using the `Visibility="Collapsed"` state will not work - the keyboard will not pop up.

Edit: Like Bertrand suggested you can also set the opacity to 0.